# Is there any benefit of stationary running indoors?

Tags: running, jogging

I ask further to [Is there any benefit of "real" running outdoors vs running on a treadmill in gym?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/40/is-there-any-benefit-of-real-running-outdoors-vs-running-on-a-treadmill-in-gym). I consulted http://www.livestrong.com/article/499092-the-advantages-of-stationary-jogging/.

How does stationary jogging compare to treadmill running? Sadly, due to time constraints, I probably can't run outdoors.

Essentially, here's my routine. Every day, I run for around 13 minutes, but hovering around a small spot. I use a musical metronome and set it to 250 beats/minute.

Answer (score 1):

There will certainly be a benefit from stationary running as compared to sitting and doing nothing. Of course Treadmill running gives you the advantage of moving forward and actually setting a speed pace. If you can't use a treadmill and you don't want to go outside then stationary running is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm starting running again after a long hiatus (I don't run much when we have a new baby so as to help my wife out) I do stationary barefoot running at a low (130-140 bpm) heart rate for 2 or 3 weeks both to build up the strength in my feet and to start conditioning my respiratory system.

I start with 15 minutes every other day for a week or so, then move up to 20 for a few times, then 25, then 30 for maybe 3 times. By then I'm usually ready to run 2 miles (ish) outdoors without completely overcooking myself.

It can get boring, I usually run in place in front of BBC Earth documentaries to ease the monotony, but I've found it to be very effective. It's (for me) no more boring than running on a treadmill, and you don't have to go anywhere to get a noticeable health benefit.